# Change path inside kustomize patch with wild card

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a kustomization with patches:

```
patches:
  - target:
      kind: PrometheusRule
      name: .*-prometheus-recording-rules
      version: v1
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: /metadata/namespace
        value: dev1
      - op: add
        path: "/spec/groups/*/rules/*/labels/namespace"
        value: dev1
```

I'm trying to create it with different namespace for every develop environment that I'm creating.

This is the error that I get `kustomize build failed: add operation does not apply: doc is missing path: "/spec/groups/*/rules/*/labels/namespace": missing value`

Is there any option to add patch with wildcards?

Comment: This is not really about kusotmize, as it is more about [RFC 6902 (`datatracker.ietf.org`)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6902). This RFC does not define wildcard  patching.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.
I'll try to achieve with replacements